# F# : A recursive value that can reference itself

Tags: recursion, f#

I have a record :

```
type node = {
               content : string;
               parent : node option;
               branch : string option;
               children : seq<node> option;
            }
```

Which I want to instantiate this way :

```
let rec treeHead = {
                       content = "Value"
                       parent = None;
                       branch = None;
                       children = tree (Some(treeHead)) rows;
                   };
```

Where

```
let rec tree (parent:node option) (rows:seq<CsvRow>) :seq<node> option
```

Is a a recursive function that gets the children of a node (to construct a tree).
So as you can see the object treeHead needs to call itself through the tree function.

I want to it this way to avoid using treeHead as a mutable value and change its children property after.

My question is that the treeHead is raising an error and a warning. The error says :

> The value 'treeHead' will be evaluated as part of its own definition.

And the warning says :

> This and other recursive references to the object(s) being defined
>   will be checked for initialization-soundness at runtime through the
>   use of a delayed reference. This is because you are defining one or
>   more recursive objects, rather than recursive functions. This warning
>   may be suppressed by using '#nowarn "40"' or '--nowarn:40'.

First, am I doing this the right way (I mean, not considering the mutable choice) ? And how should I correct this.

Comment: You can't do it this way. Immutable data structures can't have back references. Make `parent` a function `unit -> node` instead, then it will work. But I would rather recommend to reconsider the design.

Comment: With immutable data, it's usually a bad idea to have two-way references, where children reference their parent *and* the parent references its children. That's a design from the mutable-data world. I can't explain why in a comment (too few characters), but if you try to change a single node in a two-way reference design, you'd have to copy the **whole tree**. There's a "standard" way to do trees in F#, and this isn't it.

Comment: Generally, the "standard" way is: `type Tree<'a> = Leaf of 'a | Node of Tree<'a> list` where the contents of a "node" are its children. If you take the time to work through the https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds/ series, you may reach a better understanding of this structure.

Comment: @rmunn I'll consider that, thx

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/6391698/2314532 for another example of the "standard" tree structure

Comment: I'd also note that this data structure is not a tree if it has parent pointers, it is a graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing with immutable data structures is, they're immutable. *(<-- some Yoda-level stuff right there)*

With a mutable data structure, you first create yourself a box, and then start putting things into the box. One of the things you put in may be a reference to the box itself. Since you already have a box, that's fine, you can take its reference.

With an immutable data structure, this doesn't work: you have to enumerate all things that go into the box *before* the box even exists! So the box itself can't be one of these things. That's what the compiler tells you in the error message: `the value foo would be evaluated as part of its own definition`. Can't do. Bad luck.

If only you could wrap the reference to the box in such a way as to not evaluate it right away, but defer the evaluation till later, till the box is fully constructed... I know! Put it in a closure!

```
let getMe42 x = 42

type R1 = { r1: int }
let rec x1 = { r1 = getMe42 x1 }  // Doesn't work: the definition of `x1` references `x1` itself

type R2 = { r2: unit -> int }
let rec x2 = { r2 = fun() -> getMe42 x2 } // This works: the definition of `x2` only creates a _closure_ around `x2`, but doesn't reference it right away
```

Ok, so if I can create a lambda, maybe I can *cheat* the compiler by passing the lambda to another function and calling it right away?

```
let getMe42 f = printfn "%O" <| f(); 42

type R = { r: int }
let rec x = { r = getMe42 (fun () -> x) }

> System.InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
```

Damn! The Force is strong with this one. Even though the compiler can't prove that I'm being naughty during compilation, it cleverly wraps the initialization in `Lazy<T>`, so I get an error at runtime.

Interestingly enough, in the very limited case of just inserting a straight-up self-reference, without complex processing, it works:

```
type R = { r: R }
let rec x = { r = x }  // Works just fine, not even a warning.
```

You can even go all the way to the turtles:

```
type R = { r: R }
let rec x = { r = { r = { r = { r = x } } } }  // Still works!
```

This is a very special case, for whose existence I can see no sane rationale. It works, because F# compiles the backing field as `internal`, not `private`, which allows it to mutate the field after constructing the record. A corollary is, this will only work within the same assembly where the type is defined.

---

Recursive values are one of those Dark Magic features that require you to split your soul in two pieces to use. I believe the proper term is *hackrux*.

Don't do this. Just don't, ok? Come back to the light side, we have cookies too.

Comment: "Truly wonderful, the answer of you is"
and
"That is why the answer of you, accepted is"

Comment: I think the ``rec`` keyword means, you can assume the _box_ already exists, you can refer to the _box_ in its definition, but you can't open/evaluate the _box_.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: "for whose existence I can see no sane rationale". Here is a practical application of recursive values. `let rec vars = (var, VClosure(arg, vars, body)) :: vars in` http://ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/benefits/interpreter.html

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: I've been studying parsing with derivatives lately and it seems to be much harder to express in F# due to limitations around recursive values. http://matt.might.net/articles/parsing-with-derivatives/

Comment: @JonHarrop The construction of closure environment doesn't necessarily need recursive values. Could be implemented by wrapping the nested environment in a closure.