# How to initialize mutually recursive records in F#

Tags: f#, record, recursive-datastructures, mutual-recursion

I have two records that have a parent-child relationship:

```
type Parent = 
  { Number: int
    Child: Child }
and Child = 
  { String: string
    Parent: Parent }
```

I have tried initializing these using the following syntax, which doesn't work:

```
let rec parent = 
  { Number = 1
    Child = child }
and child = 
  { String = "a"
    Parent = parent }
```

this leads to

```
parent : Parent = { Number = 1
                    Child = null }
child : Child = { String = "a";
                  Parent = { Number = 1 
                             Child = null } }
```

How to I initialize these without relying on mutable fields or copy-and-update after the fact using `with`?

Comment: Why `Child` is `null` for `parent` variable? Shouldn't it have the value of the `child` variable? The `and` keyword's work is to declare both variables (`parent` and `child`) together so one can reference another. So why the `null` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the syntax to initialize it:

```
let rec parent = 
  { Number = 1
    Child = 
      { String = "a"
        Parent = parent } 
  }
```

The result is:

```
parent : Parent = { Number = 1
                    Child = { String = "a"
                              Parent = ... } }
```

Note that [as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218314/2978652), this syntax may be more accidental than intentional, and will not work for more than simple self-references (e.g. passing the recursive value into a function).