# F# load a tree from CSV file

Tags: f#, tree

I am trying to learn F# and I really like what I have seen so far.
I am trying to implement some C# code the F# way of thinking as an exercise to practice and learn.

I really apologize if it has been answered before, but I could not find an answer to solve all my problems.

We have a sales force structure where we have sales supervisors and plain sales people. A supervisor might or might not have a supervisor.

All sales data comes from another system in CSV format.
At the time of reading a record, we don't know if that SalesPerson has reports or not.

I don't seem to understand how to load the tree in the immutable world of F#. I am sure there is a way.

Our simplified legacy C# code defines (translated into Enligsh)

```
public class SalesPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SalesPerson Supervisor { get; set; }
    public List<SalesPerson> Reports { get; private set; } = new List<SalesPerson>();
    public PersonalSales double { get; set; }
    public GroupSales double { get; set; }
}
```

This is an oversimplified version of the code. However, the problem remains the same: How to load the tree?

I came up with the following F# type

```
type SalesPerson = {
    Id : int
    Supervisor : SalesPerson option
    Reports : List<SalesPerson> option
    PersonalSales : double
    GroupSales : double
}
```

I am not even sure if this the F# way of defining the type.

My problems are:

1. Supervisor points to another SalesPerson and it is immutable. If it gets replaced by a new one (because immutable data works), the reference will break.
2. Reports is immutable. I think that I could use C#'s `List<T>` but I am not sure if that is the F# way.
3. Supervisor's Reports records do not follow the Supervisor record. They might come X number of lines below and not all of them together. However, the system ensures that the Supervisor record will always come before any Reports record for that supervisor.
4. How to update GroupSales calculated field after the tree is loaded.

A sample CSV file would look like:

```
1,,100.00
2,,110.00
3,1,50.00
4,1,75.00
5,2,80.00
6,,92.00
```

So:

```
1 -> 2 reports
2 -> 1 report
3,4,5,6 -> No reports
```

I would really appreciate any "light" you might shine on these issues.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

This becomes a bit easier if you separate the tree structure into a separate type. The usual approach to immutable trees is something like this:

```
let rawData =
    [ 1, None, 100.00
      2, None, 110.00
      3, Some 1, 50.00
      4, Some 1, 75.00
      5, Some 2, 80.00
      6, None, 92.00 ]

let dataMap = rawData |> List.groupBy (fun (_, superId, _) -> superId) |> Map
let getChildrenData personId = dataMap |> Map.tryFind personId |> Option.defaultValue []

type Tree<'a> = { Data: 'a; Children : List<Tree<'a>> }

type SalesPerson = { Id : int; SupervisorId : int option; PersonalSales : double; GroupSales : double }

let salesPersonTree =
    let rec buildNode (id, superId, sales) =
        let children = getChildrenData (Some id) |> List.map buildNode
        let groupSales = (children |> List.sumBy (fun x -> x.Data.GroupSales)) + sales
        { Data = { Id = id; SupervisorId = superId; PersonalSales = sales; GroupSales = groupSales }
          Children = children }

    let topLevelItems = getChildrenData None
    topLevelItems |> List.map buildNode
```

In summary: group the data by parent and then use a recursive function build up the tree starting with the top nodes (the ones that have no parent). Because we have built all descendant nodes we finish building any given node, we can use the descendant data to calculate `GroupSales`.

You can't access the parent directly from a given node, but you do have the parent ID. As long as you keep the original `salesPeople` list you can get the full data for any given parent ID.

One advantage to having a generic Tree type is that you can have re-usable functions (e.g. map, fold, tryFind) that work on any tree.

Comment: Great.... I am starting to see how you built the structure. However, I do have point #4 that I don't know how to do. How would you do `GroupSales` ? (own `PersonalSales` + children's `PersonalSales`). I would like to calculate it just once, not everytime we ask for it. TIA, David

Comment: @CrazySpaniard That is possible because we have the descendant node data available as we build up a given node. However, it does mean delaying creating of the record type until later when we can calculate `GroupSales`. This either means a bit less type safety earlier on (as I did above, staying with unmarked tuples for longer) or creating an intermediate type for the raw data.

Comment: @CrazySpaniard And I assume that you meant `GroupSales` = `PersonalSales` + children's `GroupSales`, which is equivalent to `PersonalSales` + *descendants'* `PersonalSales`.

Comment: You are totally correct in your assumption. My English played a little trick in me ;) (children vs descendants) `GroupSales` = `PersonalSales` + children's `GroupSales` works great.

Answer (score 2):

@TheQuickBrownFox did a good job modeling your domain.

```
type Employee = { Id : int; SupervisorId : int option; PersonalSales : double }
```

Using a record / class to represent a `Tree` is an OO way of handling things,
which might be easier to grasp when you don't have lot of experience in FP.

I want to show you [a more functional approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391334/tree-representation-in-f).

```
type 'a Tree =
  | Leaf of 'a
  | Branch of 'a * 'a Tree list
```

The `Leaf` nodes are the `SalesPerson`s at the end of the hierarchy. The `Supervisor`s and all their minions are represented by `Branch`es and go all the way up.

```
type SalesMember =
  | SalesPerson of Employee
  | Supervisor of Employee * SalesMember List
```

A `Tree` would also have a root node -- there can be only one -- you could easily write a function to transform `rawData` to something like:

```
let rawData =
    [ 0, None, 0.0
      1, Some 0, 100.00
      2, Some 0, 110.00
      3, Some 1, 50.00
      4, Some 1, 75.00
      5, Some 2, 80.00
      6, Some 0, 92.00 ]

let flatList =
    rawData
    |> List.map (fun (id, superId, sales) -> 
                     {Id = id; SupervisorId = superId; PersonalSales = sales})

let getTree salesPeople =
    // To do : validate root
    let root = salesPeople |> List.find (fun p -> p.SupervisorId = None)
    let children supervisorId = 
        salesPeople |> List.filter (fun p -> p.SupervisorId = Some supervisorId)

    let rec loop employee = 
      match children employee.Id with
      | [] -> SalesPerson employee
      | list -> Supervisor (employee, List.map loop list)

    loop root

let salesForce = getTree flatList
```

To implement `GroupSales` you could expand `Supervisor`.

```
type SalesMember =
  | SalesPerson of emp : Employee
  | Supervisor of emp : Employee * reports : List<SalesMember> * groupSales : double
```

One way of building an instance of this tree is by transforming the tree from the `getTree` function. Processing, transforming and optimizing trees is a broad topic, as always [for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds-3b/) is a good place to start your journey.

**UPDATE - GroupSales**

To keep it simple I'll use only one *Discriminated Union*, setting `GroupSales` to zero on the first run. You could, however, easily adapt the code to transform to another type of `Tree`.

```
type Employee = { Id : int; SupervisorId : int option; PersonalSales : double }

type GroupSales = double
type SalesMember =
  | SalesPerson of Employee
  | Supervisor of Employee * SalesMember List * GroupSales

let rawData =
    [ 0, None, 0.
      1, Some 0, 100.00
      2, Some 0, 110.00
      3, Some 1, 50.00
      4, Some 1, 75.00
      5, Some 2, 80.00
      6, Some 0, 92.00 ]

let flatList =
    rawData
    |> List.map (fun (id, superId, sales) -> 
                     {Id = id; SupervisorId = superId; PersonalSales = sales})

let getTree salesPeople =
    let root = salesPeople |> List.find (fun p -> p.SupervisorId = None)
    let children supervisorId = 
        salesPeople |> List.filter (fun p -> p.SupervisorId = Some supervisorId)

    let rec loop employee = 
        match children employee.Id with
          | [] -> SalesPerson employee
          | list -> Supervisor (employee, List.map loop list, 0.)

    loop root

let transformTree root =
    let rec getGroupSales = function
      | SalesPerson emp 
        -> emp.PersonalSales
      | Supervisor (sup, reports, _) 
        -> sup.PersonalSales + List.sumBy getGroupSales reports

    let rec loop = function
      | Supervisor (sup, reports, _) as mem
        -> Supervisor (sup, List.map loop reports, getGroupSales mem)
      | salesPerson -> salesPerson

    loop root

let salesForce = 
    flatList 
    |> getTree
    |> transformTree
```

A less naive implementation would transform / calc `GroupSales` [bottom-up instead of top-down](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recursive-types-and-folds-2b/), allowing you to use already calculated `GroupSales`.

Comment: I used to use Leaf/Branch DUs for trees like this (with a child list) but I wonder if there is any need. If a node has an empty child list then it's a leaf. It also opens up the possibility of invalid state: You can create a Branch with an empty list. I think the DU approach makes sense when you have a fixed number of children, e.g. a binary tree.

Comment: I don't think using a DU instead of a record is any more or less functional.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox I believe there is a difference, functional languages are all about types (and functions to process them). In your design there's no distinction between a `SalesPerson` and a `Supervisor`. Consider this, you find the `groupSales` field to be better suited on `Supervisor` level, as (s)he owns the group. How would you implement this without also decorating `SalesPerson`?

Comment: I was talking about your `Tree` rather than your `SalesMember`, where I accept it makes more sense as a meaningful tag. Functional languages don't even have to be statically typed :) I think of DUs as a great type-system feature that happens to be very popular in statically typed functional languages.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox I'm not sure I understand, my `SalesMember` _is_ my `Tree` :)
I've also used the record approach in the past, e.g. solving puzzles where dead ends have empty child lists, but I find this case somewhat different. Nevertheless I wouldn't have upvoted if I thought your design was flawed.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox @Funk I woul like to thank you both. I am learning a lot from both solutions, even though I am still scratching my head on Funk´s solution on implementing `GroupSales` hahaha ;). Looking forward to keeping learning the F# way. Thanx

Comment: @CrazySpaniard Working with trees may seem a little daunting at first, just remember higher order fun and recursion will take you a long way. Added my (simplified) take on this.

Comment: @Funk I will study the new solution carefully ;) It seems to be true when they say that with FP you need to "re-wire" your brain... hahaha... Thanks  alot.

Comment: @CrazySpaniard Enjoy the ride :)