# What is the '*' used for in this example?

Tags: f#

I am trying to figure out how to design a type for trees in F# and was looking at this thread for some help [Tree Representation in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391334/tree-representation-in-f).

In it, they define:

```
type Tree =
  | Branch of string * Tree list
  | Leaf of string
```

I am not sure what the `*` operator between string and Tree is supposed to do. I have been seeing it all over the place, but don't know what to search to find the answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the Tuple type name, from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples#names-of-tuple-types)

> **Names of Tuple Types**
>
> When you write out the name of a type that is a
> tuple, you use the * symbol to separate elements. For a tuple that
> consists of an int, a float, and a string, such as (10, 10.0, "ten"),
> the type would be written as follows.

```
int * float * string
```

Answer (score 3):

In types declarations, * (asterisk) indicates pairing in a tuple:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples#names-of-tuple-types